# How to read excel files in Synapse (managed private endpoint)?

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-data-lake

With Azure Synapse I have a notebook where I read excel files located in Azure Data Lake.

Usually it worked, what changed is that now I use managed private endpoint.

When notebook is launched I have the error:

```
ServiceRequestError: Cannot connect to host adlsdev.blob.core.windows.net:443 ssl:True [Name or service not known]
```

I tried the following (worked before):

```
pd.read_excel('abfss://bronze@adlsdev.dfs.core.windows.net/test/test1.xlsx')
```

What can I do in Synapse ?

Answer (score 0):

To read excel files in Synapse (managed private endpoint) you need to use linked service.

- Create linked service on the storage account (ADLS for dfs.core.windows.net/BLOB for blob.core.windows.net endpoint According to your requirement) with (managed private endpoint) enabled integration runtime

[image]

- Approve managed private endpoint on particular storage account as shown below

[image]

- Then execute below code from your synapse notebook from this [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-secure-credentials-with-tokenlibrary?pivots=programming-language-python) for reading file from ADLS with linked service.

```py
%%pyspark
# Set the required configs
source_full_storage_account_name = "Storage_account_name.dfs.core.windows.net"
spark.conf.set(f"spark.storage.synapse.{source_full_storage_account_name}.linkedServiceName", "Linked_ervice_name")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(f"fs.azure.account.auth.type.{source_full_storage_account_name}", "SAS_Token")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(f"fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.{source_full_storage_account_name}", "com.microsoft.azure.synapse.tokenlibrary.LinkedServiceBasedSASProvider")

import pandas as pd
# Python code
df = pd.read_excel('abfss://Container_name@Storage_account_name.dfs.core.windows.net/file.xlsx')
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: I have the linked service but still same error with your code

Comment: have you approved managed private endpoint from respective ADLS?

Comment: also check this [similar issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1026786/azure-synapse-pandasdataframe-to-csv-adls-gen2-wri) is helping you

Comment: Yes I approved manually this private endpoint

Comment: Solution was to create an other managed private endpoint with blob type

Comment: Glad you found the solution.

Comment: check updated answers first point.